# Using Nutch crawler with Solr

Tags: lucene, solr, nutch

Am I able to integrate Apache Nutch crawler with the Solr Index server?

**Edit:**

One of our devs came up with a solution from these posts

1. [Running Nutch and Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunningNutchAndSolr)
2. [Update for Running Nutch and Solr](http://www.mail-archive.com/nutch-commits@lucene.apache.org/msg02227.html)

**Answer**

Yes

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to upgrade to nutch 1.0 you can use the solrindex as described in this article by Lucid Imagination: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/.

Comment: ya thats the definitive article for nutch/solr

Answer (score 1):

It's still an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-442). If you're feeling adventurous you could try applying those patches yourself, although it looks like [it's not so simple](http://www.mail-archive.com/nutch-user@lucene.apache.org/msg10872.html)

Comment: ya I'm preparing a usergroup talk on lucene so I'll test out this setup. I was hoping there was a quick Y/N answer out there

Answer (score 1):

nutch 2.x is designed to use solr as default. You can follow the steps in http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial,  or a better instruction in the book "Web Crawling and Data Mining with Apache Nutch".