# Choosing a stand-alone full-text search server: Sphinx or SOLR?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, lucene, solr, sphinx

I'm looking for a stand-alone full-text search server with the following properties:

- Must operate as a stand-alone server that can serve search requests from multiple clients
- Must be able to do "bulk indexing" by indexing the result of an SQL query: say "SELECT id, text_to_index FROM documents;"
- Must be free software and must run on Linux with MySQL as the database
- Must be fast (rules out MySQL's internal full-text search)

The alternatives I've found that have these properties are:

- Solr (based on Lucene)
- ElasticSearch (also based on Lucene)
- Sphinx

My questions:

- How do they compare?
- Have I missed any alternatives?
- I know that each use case is different, but are there certain cases where I would definitely *not* want to use a certain package?

Comment: Have you ruled out using straight Lucene? Solr is a service on top of lucene, so straight Lucene could stile be a possibility.

Comment: Does Lucene have a stand-alone server mode? I thought that was one of the things SOLR added? I haven't ruled out anything - so feel free to advocate Lucene if that is the best choice given the requirements :-)

Comment: mausch: Mainly Java but also other languages.

Comment: Personally I like Sphinx. However, during a "large" project recently, the latest release candidate (0.9.9-rc2) had show stopper bugs when using multi-value arrays (MVA). It would random results! So we moved to SOLR as to get around this. Once SOLR was up and running the performance was fine, and without the show stopper bug.

Comment: Have you looked at elasticsearch.com ?

Comment: that said, we're piping data thru xml to sphinxsearch.  rough and ugly but once done it is so freakin fast.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

I've been using Solr successfully for almost 2 years now, and have never used Sphinx, so I'm obviously biased. 
However, I'll try to keep it objective by quoting the docs or other people. I'll also take patches to my answer :-)

Similarities:

- Both Solr and Sphinx satisfy all of your requirements. They're fast and designed to index and search large bodies of data efficiently.
- Both have a long list of high-traffic sites using them ([Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers), [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/powered.html))
- Both offer commercial support. ([Solr](http://www.lucidimagination.com/), [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/consulting.html))
- Both offer client API bindings for several platforms/languages ([Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/contribs.html), [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/#head-ab1768efa59b26cbd30f1acd03b633f1d110ed47))
- Both can be distributed to increase speed and capacity ([Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#distributed), [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch))

Here are some differences:

- Solr, being an Apache project, is obviously Apache2-licensed. [Sphinx is GPLv2](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/licensing.html). This means that if you ever need to embed or extend (not just "use") Sphinx in a commercial application, you'll have to buy a commercial license ([rationale](http://www.infoworld.com/t/software-licensing/why-do-vendors-select-gpl-license-079))
- Solr is [easily embeddable](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#head-02003c15f194db1a691f8b9bb909145a60ccf498) in Java applications.
- Solr is built on top of Lucene, which is a proven technology over [8 years old](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/java/tags/LUCENE_1_0_1/) with a [*huge* user base](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/PoweredBy) (this is only a small part). Whenever Lucene gets a new feature or speedup, Solr gets it too. Many of the devs committing to Solr are also Lucene committers.
- Sphinx integrates more tightly with RDBMSs, especially MySQL.
- Solr can be [integrated with Hadoop to build distributed applications](http://highscalability.com/how-rackspace-now-uses-mapreduce-and-hadoop-query-terabytes-data)
- Solr can be [integrated with Nutch to quickly build a fully-fledged web search engine with crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211411/using-nutch-crawler-with-solr).
- Solr can [index proprietary formats like Microsoft Word, PDF, etc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler). Sphinx [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207995/indexing-word-documents-and-pdfs-with-sphinx).
- Solr comes with a [spell-checker out of the box](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent).
- Solr comes with [facet support out of the box](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview). Faceting in Sphinx [takes more work](http://api-meal.eu/memo/128-faceted-search-with-sphinx-and-php/).
- [Sphinx doesn't allow partial index updates for field data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc/737931#737931).
- In Sphinx, [all document ids must be unique unsigned non-zero integer numbers](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#data-restrictions). Solr [doesn't even require an unique key for many operations](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey), and unique keys can be either integers or strings.
- Solr supports [field collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) (currently as an additional patch only) to avoid duplicating similar results. Sphinx doesn't seem to provide any feature like this.
- While [Sphinx is designed to only retrieve document ids](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sphinx_Search#SPHINX_DOES_NOT_RETREIVE_DATA.21.21.21), in Solr you can directly get whole documents with pretty much any kind of data, making it more independent of any external data store and it saves the extra roundtrip.
- Solr, except when used embedded, runs in a [Java web container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as Tomcat or Jetty, which require [additional specific configuration and tuning](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall) (or you can use the [included Jetty](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Getting+Started) and just launch it with `java -jar start.jar`). Sphinx has no additional configuration.

Related questions:

- [Full Text Searching with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132284/full-text-searching-with-rails)
- [Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc)

Comment: Talking about devs committing to both Solr and Lucene, it seems they have merged the two products making further development easier and faster - http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/03/26/lucene-and-solr-development-have-merged/.

Comment: @Stann : how so? I've used Solr for nearly 5 years ago and never needed to write a single line of Java.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Do u really think that java code will be faster than C++. Here's the comparison made by Bill Karwin and Sphinx there queries things 10 times faster than lucene (and solr have gotta be even slower than.) http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: @Stann : do you really think you need more performance than whitehouse.gov, Netflix, The Guardian, digg, just to name a few websites using Solr? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers

Comment: @Stann : I also recommend checking out https://www.google.com/search?q=java+slow+myth

Comment: @Stann : also, Solr can actually be *faster* than Lucene due to caching, in real-world scenarios (not contrived benchmarks like Karwin's...)

Comment: [Here is an answer on Sphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql) that is a good pair to this answer on Solr

Answer (score 49):

Unless you need to extend the search functionality in any proprietary way, Sphinx is your best bet.

Sphinx advantages:

1. Development and setup is faster
2. Much better (and faster) aggregation. This was the killer feature for us.
3. Not XML. This is what ultimately ruled out Solr for us. We had to return rather large result sets (think hundreds of results) and then aggregate them ourselves since Solr aggregation was lacking. The amount of time to serialize to and from XML just absolutely killed performance. For small results sets though, it was perfectly fine.
4. Best documentation I've seen in an open source app

Solr advantages:

1. Can be extended.
2. Can hit it directly from a web app, i.e., you can have autocomplete-like searches hit the Solr server directly via AJAX.

Comment: Solr has many response writers other than xml, including JSON, PHP, Ruby, Python and a java binary format: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/request/QueryResponseWriter.html

Comment: Did I mention how terrible the Solr/Lucene documentation is? Having to root through Javadocs to figure out functionality is not my idea of documentation.

Comment: I should have linked to the wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryResponseWriter#head-e82d899e83a861380fb6d0c34c1228a2f79f6c98

Comment: I spend the whole day fixing some installation bug of sphinx 0.9.9 on my mac. So far it is still not working. It is so buggy. I used very ways suggested. I am givin up Really frustrating...

Comment: solr's documentation is not so good as sphinx. but the community is large. And I can always figure out everything by reading the source code of solr.

Answer (score 21):

Note: There are many users with the same question in mind.

So, to answer to the point:

**Which and why?**

- Use **Solr** if you intend to use it in your web-app(example-site search engine). It will definitely turn out to be great, thanks to its API. You will definitely need that power for a web-app.
- Use **Sphinx** if you want to search through tons of documents/files real quick. It indexes real fast too. I would recommend not to use it in an app that involves JSON or parsing XML to get the search results. Use it for direct dB searches. It works great on MySQL.

**Alternatives**

Although these are the giants, there are plenty more. Also, there are those that use these to power their custom frameworks. So, i would say that you really haven't missed any. Although there is one [elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org) that has a good user base.

Comment: that awkward moment when I read this answer after a year and a half and click on upvote and see that I wrote this answer myself. lol. :D A small addition to this though: After 18 months, elasticsearch has turned out to be a great alternative and has a decent community too. Cool, bonsai cool!

Comment: Augustus! That awkward moment :D. So for a python web-app what do you think is best now ? Solr or elastic search based on performance, memory usage and easiness to setup any idea ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language the web app is written in. Choose based on your use case!

Answer (score 19):

I have been using Sphinx for almost a year now, and it has been amazing.
I can index 1.5 million documents in about a minute on my MacBook, and even quicker on the server. I am also using Sphinx to limit searches to places within specific latitudes & longitudes, and it is very fast.
Also, how results are ranked is very tweakable.
Easy to install & setup, if you read a tutorial or two.
Almost 1.0 status, but their Release Candidates have been rock solid.

Comment: Geographical searching can be done in Solr with the LocalSolr plugin: http://www.gissearch.com/localsolr

Comment: you can INDEX 1.5 million documents in a minute? I can't even come close to READING that many - directly from 7zip (not writing, outputting to the console) files on my SSD! And it's 2017! What kind of documents are these? That's pretty incredible. Note: I hope you didn't mean _search_ the index of 1.5 million in a minute. Searches of an index w/ 1.5 million docs should still return in seconds (even in 2009).

Answer (score 2):

Lucene / Solr appears to be more featured and with longer years in business and a much stronger user community.
imho if you can get past the initial setup issues as some seems to have faced (not we) then I would say Lucene / Solr is your best bet.

Comment: User community is an important point. There are a couple of VERY, VERY helpful people in the Sphinx forums, but there isn't a strong community otherwise.