# word likeness/similarity in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a column that holds the genre of a movie (up to three specifiers separated by slashes) such as "comedy/romance/adventure." Is there a function or something similar in mysql or php that would allow me to take the genre of a movie and compare it with other genres of other rows and arrange them by likeness? For example, having a movie with "comedy/romance/adventure" would return movies with all three first, and then movies with 2 of those genres, and finally movies with maybe 1 of those genres.

Comment: Is it possible for you to normalize the table? then you could sort like that..

Comment: please renormalize.  this is not a good design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable [full-text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on the genre column, you can do it. I would recommend using an external full-text search engine such as sphinx to handle this, though, as MySQL's built-in full-text indexing really ain't that great.

You'd start by setting a full-text index on the genre field

`ALTER TABLE movies ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (genre);`

Then you'd be able to select from this like so:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(genre) AGAINST ('comedy romance adventure') AS relevancy FROM movies ORDER BY relevancy DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest a full-text index like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr) for relevance search.

There are a number of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr) on the subject.