# Write speed with MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

I have this big table which I want to have fulltext search, so I made it MyISAM, as InnoDB doesn't support that.

Am I gonna have performance issues if I write a lot to that table? I have been told that MyISAM locks the whole table during writes.

Do I have any other option if I need both fulltext search and non-locking write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with 3rd party solutions(that work with your MySQL database), I'd highly suggest [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) to handle your fulltext search. As you can see on their website, it is highly endorsed by the community and very supported in terms of application level interaction.

There are of course other solutions other than Sphinx, in which you can see a fantastic SO discussion comparing them here:

[Choosing a stand-alone full-text search server: Sphinx or SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr)

Answer (score 5):

If you write a lot to a MyISAM table you'll eventually have locking issues that you wouldn't with InnoDB. I recommend looking into other options for full-text search, e.g. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) 
that are both accessible from a number of languages now. See [Lucene Tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/) to get started.